# How to get SQL trace string from ObjectContext?

Tags: entity-framework-4

Is it possible to get the sql that will be executed for an update statement from an EF 4 ObjectContext?  I know how to get it from a query but not from an update/insert statement....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not directly. You can use SQL Server Profiler, a third party profiler, and or a [tracing provider](http://efwrappers.codeplex.com).

Comment: That's what I thought.  I ended up just setting a breakpoint and looking at Intellitrace.